# How do I see that $x^5+x-1=(x^2-x+1)(x^3+x^2-1)$

Tags: polynomials

I've recently been asked my friend to find the solutions to the expression $x^5+x=1$, now I haven't yet done complex analysis, but I thought I'd give it a go. I came up with a pretty, but probably useless
$$ x^2(x+1)(x^2-x+1)-(x^2-x+1)=0$$
Now Wolfram suggests this form, which looks very useful. I have, however, absolutely no idea how would one get to that.
$$(x^2-x+1)(x^3+x^2-1)=0$$
My question is then how do I get from $x^5+x-1=0$ to the expression above.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: $x^2(x+1)A-A=(x^3+x-1)A$. What is your question?

Comment: @GrigoryM, of course, you are right, I am only being blind, having not noticed that the two polynomials are identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you were almost there:

$$x^2(x+1)(x^2-x+1)-(x^2-x+1)=(x^2-x+1)(x^2(x+1)-1)=(x^2-x+1)(x^3+x^2-1)$$

Comment: Ahh the mistakes one does when dealing with things out of one's comfort zone! Of course, now I feel stupid, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Personnaly to factor this polynomial I'll try

$$(x^3+ax^2+bx\pm1)(x^2+cx\mp1)$$

Comment: Thanks for an alternative route, I was thinking something similar, will try.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Good points Sami. Indeed, it helps us :+)

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$x^2(x+1)(x^2-x+1)-(x^2-x+1)=\left(x^2(x+1)-1\right)(x^2-x+1)=(x^3+x^2-1)(x^2-x+1)$$

It is simply a matter of extracting a common factor in the terms you already have.